# Issues when loading, displaying and searching multiplication table that uses nested-loops and 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I was instructed to create a multiplication table that uses nested-loops and 2D arrays and have been working on it for days. The table has 3 functions: Load Array, Display Array, and Search Array. I am not experienced with loops, but I think I finished that part. However, although there are no errors displayed, when I debug/run the program, the "**load array**" button does nothing, the "**display array**" button displays 9 numbers at the top, then an "out of range" exception appears; and when I click "**search array**", it only works when I input a "0"... It is supposed to search the array for all occurrences of the number entered as the search criteria in the textbox. I think adding a try-catch block may help, but not sure how to fix the other issues...

Here is my code:

```
    namespace CS12c
{
    public partial class frmCS12c : Form
    {

        int [ , ] intTable = new int[9,9];  // 9 x 9 table 

        public frmCS12c()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnLoadArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int r; //row
            int c; //column
            int intResult; //result

            //Index references begin at zero 
             for (r = 0; r < intTable.GetLength(0); r++)    //Use intTable.GetLength(0) and intTable.GetLength(1) to control processing
            {

               for (c = 0; c < intTable.GetLength(1); c++) //Add 1 to the indexes before multiplying to build multiplication table 
              {
                intResult = (r + 1) * (c + 1);
                intTable[r, c] = intResult;
               }
                txtTable.AppendText("\r\n"); 
          }
      }

        //Modify the nested for loops used above to nested while loops
        private void btnDisplayArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int r; //row
            int c; //column
            string strSpace;

            txtTable.Clear(); //clear the text box

            for (r = 0; r < 9; r++)
            {

                for (c = 0; c < 9; r++)
                {

                    if (intTable[r, c] < 10)
                        strSpace = "  ";  //two spaces 
                    else
                        strSpace = " ";   //one space

                    txtTable.AppendText(strSpace); // insert space
                    txtTable.AppendText(intTable[r, c].ToString());  //insert result

                }
                    txtTable.AppendText("\r\n");  //Move down one line

            }
        }
        private void btnSearchArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int r; //row
            int c; //column
            int intSearchNumber; //Search number

            txtTable.Clear(); //clear the text box

            //Not enclosed in a try-catch; make you enter a number in textbox
            intSearchNumber = int.Parse(txtSearchNumber.Text);

            //In search display all occurences that match the search numbers
            for (r = 0; r < intTable.GetLength(0); r++)
            {

                for (c = 0; c < intTable.GetLength(1); c++)
                {

                    if (intSearchNumber == intTable[r, c])
                        txtTable.AppendText(intTable[r, c].ToString() + " is located in " + r + ", " + c);
                }
                        txtTable.AppendText("\r\n");

            }
        }


        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

    }//end of form
}//end of namespace
```

Anyone who can help would truly be a life-saver, thank you...

Comment: What do you mean that load "does nothing". What are you expecting it to do? It populates the array and appends some newlines.

Comment: Add `Try{/*Your code inside btnSearchArray_Click here*/}catch(Exception ex){MessageBox.Show(string.Format("r: {0},c: {1}",r.ToString(),c.ToString()))}`

Comment: @Pau808 You can know what index you are geting wrong there if you add `Try...Catch...`.

Comment: Don't do that, it's not what exception handling is for.

Comment: Yea...but you should delete it after debugging...also please make use of breakpoint..

Comment: @EvanTrimboli: It literally does nothing as in, the button clicks but nothing populates/happens.

Comment: So you're saying it never enters the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the "load array" button does nothing

In fact `btnLoadArray_Click` method does something - fills the `intTable` array. It doesn't do anything useful visually, so if it needs to show something, you have to write some code for that.

> "display array" button displays 9 numbers at the top, then an "out of range" exception appears

In your `btnDisplayArray_Click` handler, the following line has a bug

```
for (c = 0; c < 9; r++)
```

Notice the `r++`? Change it to `c++` and the problem is gone.

> when I click "search array", it only works when I input a "0"... It is supposed to search the array for all occurrences of the number entered as the search criteria in the textbox.

I didn't find any problems in `btnSearchArray_Click` method, it works as expected.

Actually the problems #1 and #3 might be related in case you haven't attached your `btnLoadArray_Click` method to the corresponding button `Click` event. Open your form designer.cs and make sure there is a line similar to

```
this.btnLoadArray.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnLoadArray_Click);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I cannot believe that I failed to notice an r++ instead of a c++! Going to prevent such errors in the future, and it is working much better now-- thanks again :)